# How do I enable annotation in Intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, nested

I have an intellij project which is not showing the Git annotations options [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLWUO.png).  How do I enable git annotations ? The project indeed has a git directory, however, that directory is nested underneath the main project folder.

i.e.

`project/
  some_folders/
    code/
       .git`

Hence its not there by default.

`IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IC-145.971, built on April 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b162 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new VCS directory mapping manually (from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/associating-a-directory-with-a-specific-version-control-system.html#assocDir)):

> Associating a directory with a version control system
>
> To associate a directory with a version control system, follow these
>   steps:
>
> Open version control settings (File | Settings | Version Control).
>   This page shows a list of project directories and version control
>   systems associated with them (if no directories have been added, the
>   list only contains the project root). Click the Add button  on the
>   right. In the Add VCS Directory Mapping dialog box that opens, select
>   the Directory option. Type the path to the directory that you want to
>   associate with a version control system, or click the Browse button 
>   and select the directory in the dialog that opens. From the VCS
>   drop-down list, select the version control system that will be used to
>   control the files in this directory. Note that this list only contains
>   the version control systems for which the corresponding Plugins are
>   currently enabled (see Managing Plugins for details). Optionally,
>   click the Configure VCS button that allows you to specify the settings
>   for the selected version control system. The same settings are also
>   available under the Version Control settings node. Click OK to save
>   the mapping and return to the Version Control page.